# Maximum likelihood estimator and Neyman-Pearson test statistic

Tags: hypothesis-testing, maximum-likelihood

Suppose I have a probability density function for **x**

$$ f_n( {\bf x}; \theta) = \exp(n\theta - \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i) * I(\min{{\bf x}} \ge \theta) $$

Where I is an indicator function ( = 1 if the condition inside the brackets is satisfied, 0 otherwise).

I wish to find the maximum likelihood estimator for this density function. Would I be correct in saying the MLE is the minimum observation in **x**? $$\hat{\theta}_n = \min({\bf x})$$

Next, I consider a hypothesis test $$ H_0: \theta = \theta_0 \text{ vs. } H_1: \theta \text{ > } \theta_0$$

And want to find the Neyman Pearson test statistic for the altered test $$ H_0': \theta = \theta_0 \text{ vs. } H_1': \theta = \theta_1$$

I think I am correct in thinking such a test is $$ T_{NP}({\bf x}) = \exp(n(\theta_1 - \theta_0))$$

Apparently I should be able to show that the Neyman Pearson test is equivalent to the test $$T({\bf x}) = \hat{\theta}_n$$

If someone could show me how to do this, that would be great. Then I have to determine a critical value to obtain a test at significance level alpha. But I don't know the distribution of theta hat.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $T_{NP} (\bf x)$ looks strictly wrong as it stands since you don't seem to have accounted for the conditions under which it, in fact, *is* the expression you give (the conditions are embodied by the indicator functions that should still appear in the Neyman-Pearson ratio - let this be the lesson: the indicator functions are *very* relevant to any solution).  Have a look again carefully at what happens with the indicator function in your likelihood function ($\mathcal{L}(\theta;\bf x))=f_n( {\bf x}; \theta)$): it doesn't simply cancel out when you find the Neyman-Pearson ratio, which is what you seem to have done, because $I(\min{{\bf x}} > \theta_0)$ is not the same as $I(\min{{\bf x}} > \theta_1)$, necessarily (some manipulations become easier if you assume $\theta_1>\theta_0$, although it isn't strictly necessary).

You should be able to obtain a piecewise function which is either $0$ or the expression you offer depending on the relative positions of the MLE $\hat{\theta}_n=\min(\bf x)$, $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$ (there is also an indeterminate case when the sample minimum is below both $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$, but presumably there would be no point in testing the given $H_0$ in such a case as it is immediately invalidated by the sample obtained).  You can now impose the N-P criterion on the ratio.

You can obtain the distribution of the MLE $\hat{\theta}_n=\min(\bf X)$ from expanding the distribution function 
$$P(\hat{\theta}_n<t)=1-P(\min(\bf X)\ge t)=1-P(X_1\ge t\cap X_2\ge t\cap...\cap X_n\ge t)$$
You might like to see how far you get from there using the independence of the $X_i$s.  However, due to the nature of this problem (draw, for example, the N-P ratio as a function of the sample minimum), I do not see that you are going to be able to find a critical value in the usual way.  You could, however, calculate the exact size and power for this test.

Have fun.